# Is overloading possible in two different classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, loops, overloading

Some of my friends are arguing with each other about a basic concept of OOP, is overloading possible in two different classes?

As I understand, overloading can only be done in the same class, but when it comes to the different classes it is known as overriding that is the main difference between two of them.

Is my understanding accurate?

Answer (score 3):

Overloading means having multiple methods with the same name.

It is possible for overloads to be on different classes if they have an inheritance relationship between them.

Overriding means that a class has a parent class and has methods with the *same* signature as the base class that it explicitly wants to use *instead* of the ones in the parent class. C# uses the `override` keyword to signify this.

```
public class Base
{
  protected virtual void CanBeOverridden() {}

  public void ToOverload() {}

  // An overload of ToOverload in the Base class
  public void ToOverload(int param) {}
}

public class Child : Base
{
  // override
  protected override void CanBeOverridden() {}

  // An extra overload of ToOverload in the child class
  public void ToOverload(string param) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloading is possible in different classes:

```
class Class1
{
    public void Function1(string param1);
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    public void Function1(string param1, string param2);
}
```

You then have 2 options for function1

Comment: I disagree that this is considering overloading in 2 different classes...  `Class2` by virtue of the fact that it is derived from `Class1` contains a `Function1(string param1)` method and you are overloading it with `Function1(string param1, string param2)` in the same class.

Comment: at roeland : it will give you the two different methods , not the same method of different types try to do this

Comment: create the object of class2 and u will come to know that no overloading is taking place there

Comment: I tried it. Here a screenshot: http://snag.gy/a00jv.jpg -> Notice the + 1 overload(s)